# How can I bind multiple 'Keys' to a single property on a Service Stack Request DTO

Tags: servicestack

I have a DTO that goes something like this:

```
public class Request {
 public id ASpecificIdentifier { get; set; }
 public string PreciseDescription { get; set; }
 public string FirstPartOfSomeonesName { get; set; }
}
```

Whilst I'm happy accepting this as the official 'Input', I would also like to be able to bind them to multiple keys. The reason for this will be serialized to a client in an encrypted JSON object, so I would like to keep the length down.

For example they should also be able to pass:

```
{
 "Id":1,
 "Desc":"My Issue",
 "Name":"Bob"
}
```

How can I achieve this? I have looked around at the Attributes supplied but non seem to be able to allow this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **create multiple DTOs for each scenario** you allow (set of named parameters). Then in your service you would have to handle each DTO and translate them a common DTO to take action.

**Or** Another way would be to have a **DTO that takes a generic key/value parameter**. This will make your DTOs very flexible but you will lose some of the advantages of strong typing.

For Example:

`public class Request {
   Dictionary<string,string> Properties { get; set; }
}`

Comment: Thanks, perhaps I would be better off just sticking with the long names on the service call and translate the short names in JS before they are sent to the server.